# Uploading (updating) config files into a running ZooKeeper (SolrCloud)

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I want to be able to add new collections to my SolrCloud dynamically. But to add a collection I have to upload the config file into ZooKeeper first, right?
But how can I do that without restarting ZooKeeper and my Solr instance?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SOLR4.0+ then you dont have to restart the SOLR instances.

http://technical-fundas.blogspot.in/2014/07/solr-reload-solrconfigxml-and-schemaxml.html

And When you upload the config files zookeeper, you neither have to restart the zookeeper as well.

Steps:

1) Upload the solrconfig.xml / schema.xml file in zookeeper

2) RUN reload command

http://technical-fundas.blogspot.in/2014/07/solr-reload-solrconfigxml-and-schemaxml.html

Hope this answers to your question...